# Count what is in a row based on specific criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large table of data with names in the first column and then data that applies to those names going out right for varying ranges (see example below).  On another sheet I have a space to type in the users name.  Each column of data below represents a week's worth (this varies as new users are added).

Basically what I want to do is type in the users name on Sheet B and then have a formula that goes to Sheet A, finds the user, and then counts out how many cells in that row contain data where I can then find how many weeks of data I have on that user (this is then used in trending formulas which I can get to work).

```
    Sheet A
    User    Data1    Data2     Data3
    Roger   1        .16       10
    Sam     4       
    Beth    3        

    Sheet B
    Roger has "3" week(s) worth of data
```

Any Ideas on how to do this with a formula?  Or will I need to apply VBA to the cell where I want the counts returned?

I hope this makes sense and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET('Sheet A'!1:1,MATCH(A1,'Sheet A'!A:A,0)-1,0))-1
```

on Sheet 2, where `A1` contains Name to look up

Comment: Fantastic.  That worked perfectly!! I honestly never would have thought to use OFFSET!  Thank you!